# Podio Doc about files download

Tags: podio

According to this: https://developers.podio.com/doc/files/download-file-1004147
This endpoint have a "public" part. How can we use it? If I follow the request token (that is also public) I don't have to provide anything in header. But should I include something in the request like api secret and key? There's no explanation on "public" request in the docs.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ups, that was an error in Podio documentation. Thanks for asking about it, we've fixed it now :)

https://developers.podio.com/doc/files/download-file-1004147 is not `Public` method, you have to send regular Authorization header to that endpoint to authenticate for the download.

Comment: Thanks! I think podio should have a "Public" option in app setting to allow direct download of files from Outside of Podio.

Comment: Podio is not designed as file sharing platform, so we won't add this feature :) But you can connect with multiple file sharing services (e.g. Sharefile, Google, Dropbox, etc) and store files on those services and keep them linked to Podio item.